# Why do my results print with the character [?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-agent

Here is my code :

```
useragent_list = list()
with open("agent.txt") as file:
  for line in file:
     agent = line.split(':')
     useragent_list.append((agent))
  print(agent)
```

And here is the printed result :

```
['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36\n']
```

How can I print the output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Why are you doing `.split(':')`?

Comment: `split` returns a list. Square brackets mean the thing you're printing is a list. Did you not want a list?

Comment: thank you for your reply , i want to do useragent in order 1,2,3..... I am new to python . What should I do to be able to do it?

Comment: ... So why are you splitting on `:`? Does your file even contain that character? What do you actually want to do if it does?

Comment: if I don't put (':') , it shows : ['Mozilla/5.0', '(Windows', 'NT', '10.0;', . I don't know what to do with it

Comment: How can I print the output: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36

Comment: all i want to do is get the contents of the txt file in order from top to bottom . please help me

Comment: print(agent[0]) try this

Comment: How about you skip agent and just print `line` instead?

Comment: i want to open profiles with chrome driver , each time i open it use user agent in list txt . list txt sorted:
line 1 = useragent 1
line2 = useragent 2
...

Comment: Then just use `line` as the user agent. There's no reason or need to use `split()`

Comment: `for line in file: print(line.strip())`

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned,
What you've got is a list, even if that's not what you meant to do. Any time you want to see just one part of a list (in this case just the one element of the list) you need to specify which element you mean. In this case, since it's the only item in the list and lists in Python are zero-indexed you want to ask for the 0th index like this:

```
useragent_list = list()
agent = None #had to add this bit bc errors
with open("agent.txt") as file:
  for line in file:
     agent = line.split(':')
     useragent_list.append((agent))
  print(agent[0]) #note the 0 added in brackets
```

Tested this out and it seems to do exactly what you're trying to do (at least with what you've provided).

Comment: I just posted my full code, can you review it for me?

Comment: @ThanhVN did you try this?  If you did and it wasn't satisfactory what is the remaining problem?

Comment: when i use your code . chrome will automatically select the last useragent. Can you review the code below for me?

Comment: Not seeing your code anywhere, clicked the link and it just takes me to the the top of this page. 

If you're trying to see what's in your user_agent list, you need to be looking at that, not the agent variable (having the same word in your variable in no way ties them together). 
So try print(useragent_list[i]) where i is the index you want to print. If you want to print them all you need a loop.